# Raspberry microkernel, doesn't seems to do anything

Tags: c, linux, arm, kernel, raspberry-pi

I did last year, during my studies, an x86 microkernel and that was really interesting. As I like it, and I like raspberry development too, I just begin to try to develop a really light micro-kernel using this tutorial : http://wiki.osdev.org/ARM_RaspberryPi_Tutorial_C.

My problem is that, when I test my code, on my rpi or on qemu, I don't get anything on the output, and, the thing that I don't understand is : should I really have something on the output after just writing the uart0 driver and trying to use it?

My rpi is connected to the monitor using hdmi. For qemu, I use volatilepb configuration with arm1176 cpu.

However, if someone has any advice or useful links for raspberry kernel dev, that would be great...

I hope my question was clear and my English not so bad..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't call that a kernel, it's just a program without OS. Nevertheless, this should display

> Hello World, feel the echo

Did you take the following note into account ?

> Note that currently the QEMU "raspi" emulation may incorrectly load the kernel binaries at 0x10000 instead of 0x8000, so if you do not see any output, try adjusting the base address constant in the linker script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes I know that it's not a kernel, but I just use it as first entry point into kernel dev for raspi because I thought it was more simple. And Yes I saw it, but the thing is I can't get the 'raspi' binding for QEMU because the github link given in the tutorial is no longer available... That's why I use the 'versatilepb' binding but I don't know if it's the good way...

Comment: Moreover, I think that the binary is well loaded because I can debug, but that just displays anything...